# Resource quantity decrease for temporarily maintenance

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I am using the Resources to configure multiple types of bookable on my website as suggested in the documentation. This way, we have for a specific Product P, for example:

Resource A quantity: 50
Resource B quantity: 50

However, I need to temporarily decrease the quantity on a specific date due to maintenance. So, the question is, how to decrease the quantity in a specific date period without jeopardizing the remaining period of the month/year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I discussed this point with the development team, and they said that we don't have this option on the plugin. The solution was to create specific resources for particular days and disable the other resources on that day. In other words, use multiple resources with the availability configuration.